# What and where was the Cloak Tower?

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, lore

**What I Want to Know**

In the Dungeons and Dragons 4th Edition Neverwinter Campaign Setting (NCS), there is a building called Cloak Tower.

The NCS says this about Cloak Tower:

> The tower takes its name from a guild of mages called the Many-Starred Cloaks who lived and gathered there. They were well known in the city for their arcane skill and for the whimsical, colorful cloaks they wore. During the Spellplague, the tower and its occupants vanished. The tower reappeared half a year later on a different patch of ground in the city.

However, the book doesn't make it at all clear where the tower was previously or what its function was. It's also not at all clear how or why it might have moved, or where it went while it was gone.

If the tower is based on something from previous editions, then perhaps someone here knows more about it.

What was the cloak tower before it disappeared? Where was it? Where did it go? What happened to the mages?

---

**Why I Want to Know**

My campaign's last session went off the rails a bit and I had to improvise. As a result, the party has found a teleportation engine in the tower's basement, reactivated it, and teleported the whole tower as well themselves and all of its occupants (an army of orcs) to places unknown. I decided the engine would continue to randomly teleport them until it was turned off. So far they've visited a pocket of the astral sea that consisted of nothing, and a volcanic scene in the elemental chaos. I need to decide where the tower is going to end up, and how to get them back to Neverwinter. Knowing where the tower came from and where it went might inform my plan, or at least lead to a more interesting adventure in the tower.

Comment: I believe that 4e is the first time Neverwinter has got this degree of detail. If so, that would mean all these details are it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not entirely - the Many-Starred Cloak and the Cloaktower existed in the *Neverwinter Nights* games.

Comment: @Miniman I found [this article](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Many-Starred_Cloak) about the tower in Neverwinter Nights. There's not much there, but it says it's in the Castle District. I also ran across [this forum discussion](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=17019), which quotes something called *Volo's Guide to the North* as saying that "At the spot where the Neverwinter River flows into the city stands the Cloaktower(42). This is the meeting place and citadel of the Many-Starred Cloak". The castle is where the river flows out of the city though...

Comment: @DCShannon Volo's guides are from 2e, and I believe Neverwinter has been destroyed and rebuilt between then and 4e, so it's not infeasible that the castle might have moved.

Comment: From memory, Volo's Guide to the North is available in .pdf form from some online RPG stores. Perhaps someone who's read it could say if it's worth looking up?

Comment: @GMJoe I actually found a copy already. I'll probably take a look at it and these other resources and write some kind of answer before my next session, unless somebody beats me to it.

Answer (score 5):

In the Neverwinter Nights game campaign (based on the D&D 3.5) the Cloaktower was next to the Temple of Tyr in the City Core. As others said, the city has been destroyed and rebuilt since that time. And, as already mentioned, it was as a guildhall of the Many-Starred Cloak wizards which assisted in the rule of Lord Nasher.

Answer (score 0):

> What was the cloak tower before it disappeared? Where was it? Where did it go? What happened to the mages?

I think those questions were left open on purpose, so that each DM could fit the answer to their personal campaign. It fills the same slot as asking "what caused the Day of Mourning" on Eberron.

> If the tower is based on something from previous editions, then perhaps someone here knows more about it.

Personally, I don't remember any mention of this tower in any 3rd edition book of Forgotten Realms, or the [4e FRCS](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106205859/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/218287200). So I believe it is new to Neverwinter Campaign Setting.

I think it is worthy to say that this tower is also presented as a [playable dungeon](https://neverwinter.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cloak_Tower) in the [Neverwinter Online](https://store.steampowered.com/app/109600/) game, so you might consider things found in the game as canon. Unfortunately, I'm not a player of this game, so I don't know how they handled it there.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I believe, Neverwinter Nights 1 had that tower too. It could be a different tower that I remember, though. It has been somme time and I can't check atm...

Comment: The Cloak Tower was the magical item shop in Neverwinter Nights 1. You could even become a member of the Many-Starred Cloak for certain benefits, so it is not a new invention in 4e.